# Emulator not able to find thumbnails files

Tags: android, gallery, jpeg, thumbnails, image

And thank for your help.

I pushed some Jpgs on my Emulator, I run the SDCard Scan form the Media Provider tool, 
so the pushed picture shows correctly in the Gallery.

I have an activity that queries the 'MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails'

The cursor works correctly, and it finds the path to the thumbnails.

But when I run the application the Logcat shows me that he is actually unable to open the files in the path:

```
02-14 13:45:08.015: E/BitmapFactory(931): Unable to decode stream:    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails/1360429937982.jpg: open failed:    ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-14 13:45:08.046: E/BitmapFactory(931): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails/1360503332805.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-14 13:45:08.076: E/BitmapFactory(931): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails/1360525871295.jpg: open failed:   ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-14 13:45:08.095: E/BitmapFactory(931): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails/1360525870839.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-14 13:45:08.135: E/BitmapFactory(931): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails/1360525870385.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Thank you very much your help very much appreciated

Comment: Can you verify that these files do definitely exist on the emulator? in the same folder, and with the exact same name?

Comment: @FoamyGuy actually I cannot find the thumbnails files on the Emulator via the DDMS, apparently they do not exist.....

Answer (score 0):

OK,
Problem solved, when I restarted the Emulator I asked to "Wipe User Data"; 
than again run DCard Scan form the Media Provider tool, and for the time being everything works fine.

Thanks anyway!!!